# Proving limit using $\epsilon - N$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am not sure I understand the $N - \epsilon$ method for proving the equality of a limit.

I have a past mid-semester exam question that has:
$$\lim \limits_{x \to 1} (x^2 - 4x) = -3$$

Now it seems I want to take the $-3$ over $\rightarrow$ $|x^2 - 4x + 3| \lt \epsilon$ $$\text{  }\text{  }\text{  }\text{  }\text{  }\text{  }\text{  }\text{  }\text{  }\text{  }\text{  }\text{  }|x-3||x-1| \lt \epsilon$$

I now want to set $n \geq N$ where $N \in \mathbb{N}$ is some function $N(\epsilon)$

I am unsure how to continue this problem. There is only one type of question that I know how to approach(given that it is all that the lecturer has went over), which is questions with limits of fractions, where N = $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ so when I sub N in for n, $\epsilon$ goes to the top.

How would one approach these problems in general?

Comment: You could join forces with [this other user](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/725798/).

Comment: @Did Odd coincidence!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$N$ is generally used to represent a natural number and hence is used in proving limits of sequences. I would prefer to use $\delta$ here since this is the limit of a function. You are required to prove the fact that $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = l$ The way to approach this is as follows.

You begin with $ |f(x) - l| $ and try to bound it by $ |x - a| $. That is you should be able to get into a position to make $ |x^2 - 4x + 3| $ as small as you want by making $ |x - 1| $ as small as you want. Let's begin:

$$ |x^2 - 4x + 3| = |x - 3||x - 1| = |x - 1 - 2 ||x - 1| \le |x - 1|^2 + 2|x - 1| $$

Now for ease choose $ \delta \le 1$. Then $ \delta^2 \le \delta$ and hence $ \delta^2 + 2\delta \le 3\delta $. Therefore if we choose $ \delta = \text{Min} \{1, \frac{\epsilon}{3} \}$ we would have that $|x^2 - 4x + 3| \lt \epsilon $ whenever $|x - 1| \lt \delta$.

$\mathscr{Q.E.D.}$

Comment: What if $a = \infty$? I can't have bounding $|x - \infty|$

Comment: Actually, it just occurred to me that your initial sentence covers that. This actual question was in regards to a function, but another question is in regards to a sequence! Good call.

Answer (score 1):

You want to estimate $|x - 3|$. One way to get an upper bound for this is to use the triangle inequality: $|x - 3| =|(x - 1) + 2| \longleftarrow |x - 1| + |2| = |x - 1| + 2$. So if you let $|x - 1| \lt 1$, then $|x - 3| \lt 1 + 2 = 3$. So $|x - 3| \cdot |x - 1| \lt 3|x - 1|$. And you need $3|x - 1| \lt e$. All you need is once more that : $|x - 1| \lt \frac{e}{3}$. So this gives you a way to choose $d$. And you see that $d =$ min{$1, \frac{e}{3}$} fits the bill. You're done.

Answer (score 1):

You can also proof this using sequences, this is probably what you meant to say. Consider a sequence $(x_n)\to 1$ we shall show that $(f(x_n))\to -3$. The first thing to do is obtain an estimate

$$|x_n^2-4x_n+3|=|x_n-1||x_n-3|\le|x_n-1|(|x_n|+3)$$

Given $\varepsilon>0$, choose $n_0(\varepsilon/5)$  such that $|x_n-1|<\varepsilon/5$ and $|x_n-1|<1$ are both satisfied for all $n\ge n_0(\varepsilon/5)$ (this is possible since $(x_n)\to 1$ by hypothesis). In particular the last inequality imply $|x_n|<2$. Thus

$$|x_n-1|(|x_n|+3)<5|x_n-1|< \varepsilon$$

which shows that  $(f(x_n))\to -3$. Since $(x_n)$ was an arbitrary sequence converging to $1$, then it holds for all sequences converging to $1$. Thus $\lim_{x\to 1} x^2-4x=-3$.

**Remark**: Both definition of limit are logically equivalent.

Comment: Yes you are right. The question on my assignment was a question in regards to sequences, but the question I posted here from a past mid sem was in regards to a function. This is definitely helpful! Thank you.

Comment: Why is $n_0 (\frac{\epsilon}{5})$?

Comment: @DisplayName: Because we find a bound for $|x_n|$ which is $2$ (is crude but any works). Then $|x_n-1|(|x|+3)<5|x_n-1|$

Comment: What exactly is my end requirement to have a working proof for $\epsilon - N$? What statement must I show? If $n \geq N \longrightarrow$ $|a_n - a| \lt \epsilon$ when $\epsilon \gt 0$?

Comment: Am I just trying to show $|a_n - a| \lt 0$?

Comment: @DisplayName: You are trying to show that $a_n-a\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. So given a $\varepsilon$ there is a $N_\varepsilon$ such that $|a_n-a|< \varepsilon$ for all $n\ge N_\varepsilon$

Answer (score 0):

Continue reasoning. The values of $x$ you are restricting to are somewhere near $1$. Let's say now and forever that we will demand the distance from $1$, which I'll call $\delta$, is at most $1$. (I'm not quite sure what you mean by $N$ - I suspect you would call my $\delta = \frac{1}{N}$). I do this so that I can say that $|x-3| < 3$ for all $x$ in my $\delta$ ball around $1$.

So then we're reduced to $3|x-1| < \epsilon$ being our goal, or rather $|x - 1| < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$. As we control exactly how far $x$ can be from $1$, we see that as long as $\delta < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$ (or is $1$ if $\epsilon$ is very large for some reason), we get the desired proof of the limit.

Comment: What do you mean when referring to $\delta$ as a ball?

Comment: By that, I mean a ball of radius $\delta$ around $1$. This is how I interpret the $\epsilon \delta$ formula of a limit, usually: for any $\epsilon$, I can restrict my function to a small enough $\delta$ ball around the point where the values of the function are within $\epsilon$ of the limit.