# Proving $\lim_{x \to 1}x^2-4x= -3$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm confused on the use of Cauchy to prove the limit in the title. Here's what I did so far, but I think I'm wrong. So Cauchy says that if $|x_n - x_{n+1}| < \epsilon$ for all positive $\epsilon$ and sufficiently large $n$ then $x_n \to x$. Take $f(x)=x^2-4x$. If you take any sequence that converges to 1 to be $\{x_n : n>1\}$ (I think that's the right notation) then we want to prove that $y_n = f(x_n)$ converges to $-3$ which is equivalent to $|y_n - y_{n+1}| < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon$ and large $n$. So then you can take $n$ to infinity and you get $|y_n - (-3)| < \epsilon$ for large $n$. So $|f(x_n) + 3| < \epsilon$ and since $f(x_n) \to f(1)$ if $x_n \to 1$ we can make $|f(x_n) + 3|$ arbitratily small and thus satisfy Cauchy and prove the original limit. Did I do that right? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Cauchy says that? I doubt it very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to show that $x^2-4x$ converges to $-3$ as $x\rightarrow1$, that is, to prove that there exists $N$ such that $|x_n^2-4x_n+3|<\epsilon$ holds for any $\epsilon>0$ and every $n>N$.

So we should start with the given condition, $x\rightarrow1$. It says, there exists $N'$ such that for any $\epsilon'>0$ and every $n>N'$ that $|x_n-1|<\epsilon'$ always holds. So we have 
$$|x_n^2-4x_n+3|=|x_n-1||x_n-1-2|\le|x_n-1|(|x_n-1|+2)<\epsilon'(\epsilon'+2)=\epsilon$$
We could just let $\epsilon=\epsilon'(\epsilon'+2)$, noting that any $\epsilon>0$ has a corresponding value of $\epsilon'>0$, so that for every $n>N'$, $|x_n^2-4x_n+3|<\epsilon$ holds.

These complete the proof.

Comment: How do you get the first sentence? Does that follow from Cauchy's convergence criterion?

Comment: Which sentence? You mean how do I get $x\rightarrow 1$? That's a premise. I just assumed a sequence $(x_n)$ that converges to 1. So the limit of the sequence is 1. Thus I got the $\epsilon-N$ statement.

Answer (score 0):

To prove the limit, the simplest approach would be to note that, for every $x$ such that $|x-1|\leqslant1$, one has $|x-3|\leqslant3$ hence
$$
|x^2-4x-(-3)|=|x-3|\cdot|x-1|\leqslant3\cdot|x-1|.
$$